# PHP MVC & AJAX - AJAX does not call function from controller

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, model-view-controller

So I am trying to learn AJAX requests, and in testing purposes, I am trying to use it in my personal project. I set up some test functions here and there, to test out how I can use AJAX in my project, and I got on an issue.

I'm making an AJAX call from script tags in my html, but it appears to just return all the html of that page.

AJAX call code is:

```
            $.ajax({
            URL: "<?php echo URLROOT;?>tasks/setcompleted",
            type: "GET",
            data: {id:'3'},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(res){
                console.log(res);
            }
        });
```

PHP Tasks controllers method `setcompleted()` code is just a simple echo of data passed from AJAX request via GET:

```
        public function setcompleted(){
            if(isset($_GET['id'])){
                echo $_GET['id'];
            }
        }
```

I did some research, and found similar questions here, that suggested to check the URL that is passed to AJAX request. I  did that, the URL that is passed in AJAX request is correct and works, if I manually write it into browser and add necessary parameters for the GET.

Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns nothing.

```
public function setcompleted()
{
    if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $output = json_encode($_GET['id']);
 }
          return $output;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you!
Tried this, still returns only html code of page from which I am doing that AJAX request.